# Relaunch app without leaving single-app mode

Tags: mdm, airwatch

I am using AirWatch and I have devices configured in `Single-App Mode`. I would like my app relaunched right after I push a new version and it is installed.

How could I achieve that without leaving the `Single-App Mode`?

Comment: Hope my edit didn't change your question but it's the way I understood it ;)

Comment: Don't think it is possible. Have you tried it with a single device? I suppose it for a big update process but how many devices are concerned?

Comment: Testing with a single device now. Managing nine devices within a month, potentially hundreds thereafter.

Comment: That's what I thought, because if you have a low number of devices, it'd be easier to delete and reinstall  the app through the console. If it doesn't update your app, maybe a restart of the device could do the trick too